# How do you know the velocity of rotation Dynamic Rigidbody and then independently rotated Kinematic Rigidbody with this velocity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-physics

I was able to move in the right direction, but it rotates incorrectly (the wrong way)!
I do so in Unity 5:

```
Vector3 _veloMove;
Vector3 _rotation;

void Start()
{
 body = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

void OnCollisionExit() 
{
  _veloMove = body.velocity;
  _rotation = body.angularVelocity;
  isKinematic = true;
}

FixedUpdate()
{
    if (body.isKinematic)
    {
     body.MovePosition(transform.position + _veloMove * time;
     body.MoveRotation(transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler(_rotation * Time.fixedDeltaTime));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this might be your issue:

```
transform.rotation * Quaternion.Euler
```

try making that into

```
transform.rotation + Quaternion.Euler
```

and see if that works.